# Any insight as to why I'm getting Expression Expected?

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
MessageBox.Show("Unknown Error:" & Err().ToString & " " & Error(Err), 6 "Call MIS")
```

So this is my code and I'm getting an Error Expected at the "Error(Err), section and I've been looking for about a day and I can't figure it out.

Comment: What is Error?  What is in Err?  It looks like Error is a collection of some kind that is being indexed by Err.

Comment: Are you perhaps missing a comma after `6` - or should that even be there in the first place?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - good catch.

Comment: I tried removing the 6 and adding a comma after and it hasn't helped any I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you're actually trying to achieve, instead of making us guess. ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: was just updating old code from my boss's archives. I have no idea myself what the code does I just know it was throwing me a loop and I couldn't figure it out apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re your comment on my other answer, here's how we do error handling in VB.net:

```
Try
  'this code explodes with NullReferenceException
  Dim x As String = Nothing
  Dim y = x.Length

  'this code explodes for different reasons (IndexOutOfRange)
  Dim a As String = "a"
  Dim b = a(100) 'get 101st character

Catch NullReferenceException nrex
  MessageBox.Show("Something was nothing: " & nrex.Message)

Catch IndexOutOfRangeException ioorex
  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Something went too far: {0}", ioorex.Message))

Catch Exception ex
  MessageBox.Show($"I've no idea what went wrong {ex.Message}")

End Try
```

I've used 3 different ways to build an error message (string concat, string format, string interpolate), and shown how we catch multiple different kinds of exception in the same code; we can be specific (catch null ref) or general (exception) - general will catch anything that is a subclass of exception

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Err()` and `Error(...)` are valid things (I couldn't think of what they might be; Err() looks like a function, Error looks like a function/array but one cannot use the word `Error` as an identifier...)

Start simple, with this:

```
MessageBox.Show($"Unknown Error: {Err()} {Error(Err)}")
```

Then add a Title:

```
MessageBox.Show($"Unknown Error: {Err()} {Error(Err)}", "Call the police!")
```

Then change the buttons:

```
MessageBox.Show($"Unknown Error: {Err()} {Error(Err)}", "Call the police?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
```

Then capture what button the user pressed, and do something with it:

```
Dim r = MessageBox.Show($"Unknown Error: {Err()} {Error(Err)}", "Call the police?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

If r = DialogResult.Yes Then Call(police)
```

Comment: So turns out I was using OLD school vb6 and instead of Err().ToString I needed Err.Description
and for the number 6 I needed Err.Number

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageBox.Show("Unknown Error:" & Err().ToString & " " & Error(Err), 6 "Call MIS")
```

This could is Old school VB6 style and won't work in VB.NET

```
MessageBox.Show("Unknown Error:" & Err.Description & " " & Err.Number, "Call MIS")
```

This is what the code should actually look like to work in VB.NET

Comment: Should have told us what Err was.  By description!

Comment: Afraid to give out too much as it was my boss's old code from vb6 and he has me updating it apologies!